# Passing variable that detects specific button in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, if-statement

I created function that recognize which post has been clicked on.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery(.recognize-post).on("click", function() {
              var clickedButton = jQuery(this).data("id")
              console.log("click button with post id: ", clickedButton)
              button-id = "recognize-post"
    ...
    ...
})
})
}
```

html

```
<button id="recognize-post" class="recognize-post" data-id="<?php the_title() ?>">POST</button>
```

Code above works perfectly and in recognizes the correct post, but I need to pass `clickedButton` outside of this function and I don't know how to do so.

I need to have it in `else if` function, this is my attempt

```
else () {
...
} else if (button-id === "recognize-post") {
console.log(clickedButton)
}
```

Here the problem comes, `clickedButton` is **underfined** and need it to recognize post in exactly the same way how in on click function. Is it possible?

Comment: You need to check if it's `undefined` - to see if a button has been clicked yet.   Then you need to move your `clickedButton` variable so that it's in the same scope as where you need to use (probably globally would be easiest)

Comment: Note `button-id` is not a valid variable name,  Did you mean `else if (clickedButton ==`

Comment: It's not clear where your "else if function" is located. Why not just put that logic inside the `click` handler?

Comment: it's a long file with lot of functions in. Both, mentioned on click function and if else statement are in `jQuery(document).ready(function() {......}` and then there's on click function and outside of that almost in the end of the file is else if statement

Comment: button-id is globaly declared as empty string @freedomn-m

Comment: Can you provide a working snippet of jsfiddle.net that show `var button-id=""`?  Because it's not valid in javascript, so I'm wondering exactly what you're doing.

Comment: I tried to do something for better understanding @freedomn-m https://jsfiddle.net/56t7m3hs/

Comment: Right, it's `buttonID` not `button-id` - they're not the same thing.   Possibly minor, but important.

Comment: As noted:  Move `let buttonID = ""` to the same scope as the `if`:  Here's the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/32v0qgmy/).  Separately, you don't need doc.ready inside a doc.ready (no harm, just don't need it).  This assumes your code at the bottom is in the same file/application as the button click code - the comment *"open calendar in specific calendar provider"* - so goes back to the above question from @Bergi - where/when does that code run?  As is, in the fiddle, buttonID won't have a value as you haven't clicked yet.

Comment: I corrected fiddle jsfiddle.net/56t7m3hs , code is wrapped in first doc.ready, then function for recognizing the post (which button was clicked) and then if statement. It is still underfined, even though I click on it, post button is not recognized in else if statement still

Comment: Also note that I am looking for clickedBtnID not for buttonID

Answer (score 0):

You can make a separate function that takes in the information you want to preserve.

```js
// make a new function
function doSomethingWithTheIdAndBtn(id, btn) {
 // take in arguments that represent the id or btn or whatever you need
    else () {
    ...
    } else if (id === "recognize-post") {
    console.log(btn)
}

}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       jQuery(.recognize-post).on("click", function() {
              var clickedButton = jQuery(this).data("id")
              console.log("click button with post id: ", clickedButton)
              button-id = "recognize-post"
              doSomethingWithTheIdAndBtn(button-id, clickedBtn) // call the function
    ...
    ...
})
})
}
```

Answer (score -1):

So, the issue here is that if you declare a variable function in a given "[scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope)" — in your case, the anonymous function's scope — it will only be defined inside of that scope. If you want to use the variable outside of the function, you need to declare it outside of the function.

So, for instance, if your code was

```js
function foo() {
    var myVariable = 0;
}
foo();
// This will throw an error, cuz myVariable is not defined in this scope
console.log(myVariable);
```

you could fix it by declaring the variable outside of the function's scope

```js
var myVariable; // declare it outside of the function

function foo() {
    myVariable = 0; // give it a value inside of the function
}
foo(); // call foo so that myVariable has a value

console.log(myVariable); // this will print 0. Success!
```

Comment: Thanks @EKW, but how can I declare it outside? The declared variable `clickedButton` is depended on "click", if I declare it outside, it won't recognize which post has been clicked.

Comment: *if I declare it outside, it won't recognize which post has been clicked* - it will *after* you click the button - before you click the button, it makes no sense anyway.

Comment: I tried to wrap the whole `jQuery(document).ready............` into `function foo() {..}` I called the function and `console.log` declared variable outside of function's scope, it did not give me the correct results.